# One to Many association problem in LINQ to SQL

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following associated property in my `Employee` class, where `EmployeePhoneNumber` is related, as the attributes declare, in the DB.

```
[TableAttribute(Name = "dbo.EmoployeePhoneNumber")]
public class EmployeePhoneNumber
```

and

```
[TableAttribute(Name = "dbo.Employee")]
public class Employee
{
    [ColumnAttribute(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Association(Name = "Employee_EmployeePhoneNumbers", ThisKey = "ID", OtherKey = "EmployeeID")]
    public EntitySet<EmployeePhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

When I try and access `GetTable<Employee>()`, I get the error:

> Invalid association mapping for member
>   'Interview.Web.Models.Employee.PhoneNumbers'. 
>   'Interview.Web.Models.EmployeePhoneNumber' is not an entity.

I am very new to LINQ to SQL, being an EF man used to the model designer, and I have to code these models by hand.

Comment: There is a design surface for LINQ-to-SQL too, you realise. Or you can use .dbml as a code-generator, even without the designer... just saying...

Comment: Sorry @Marc, I forgot to add the Homework tag when I posted.  There is no 'model' as I'm supposed to deal with 'hand rolled' entity classes.  I'm not shy to ask about this here, as one of my selling points, and I hope one being sought, is solving problems, using the internet (and thus community) when the problem is outside our normal thought park.

Comment: the hand-rolled code is still your "model".

Comment: I meant a model with lavish metadata, described by XML and accessible through a designer.  I generated one, and basically copied the generated association into my own code, with no change.

Comment: does your EmployeePhoneNumber class have an ColumnAttribute with IsPrimaryKey=true ?

Comment: Thank you @DarkSquirrel42, that seems to have been the issue.  The error message wasn't as helpful as you though.  Why not post this as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ColumnAttribute with IsPrimaryKey=true missing in EmployeePhoneNumber

Comment: Following blog post describes this in detail (very helpful imho): http://www.bartlannoeye.be/blog/linq-to-sql-not-generating-code-for-association

Comment: new link: https://www.bartlannoeye.com/blog/linq-to-sql-not-generating-code-for-association/